# Can drywall cover a 30" span on the ceiling?

Tags: drywall

These rafters span 30". Do you think I can hang 1/2" over this span or should I go 5/8"

Or go extreme and run 2x4's perpendicular, 24" OC?
[image: ceiling]

Comment: I think you would be asking for sagging ceilings even with 5/8" at over 24" especially if there are large exterior temperature swings. Most exposed beam roofs like this only have a deck and the temp swings can cause cracking and sagging. I would use hat channel attached to the beams on 16"s and hat channel is easier to install IMO.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't just decorative beams? The gable slope meets the wall, above the rim, and the walls and ceiling look like drywall, behind the wood work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opinion - you're nuts to bury those nice exposed beams. But, no accounting for taste.

5/8" might span it, though you'll end up with a lot of 6" scraps due to 90 rather than 96" spacing. 1/2" not a chance - it will sag badly.

If you strap it, you only need 1x3, and you don't (IMHO) want it 24" apart which is already a marginal spacing on ceilings - put it 16" or even 12" apart. Actually, if you can find steel resilient channel (AKA furring channel or hat channel or U-channel), that might work just as well and be a lot straighter than the average wood 1x3 or 2x4 you can get these days.

Might as well insulate up there if you are burying the beams.